# HP Proliant 365 G1 HP Smart Array p400i

Tags: linux

has anyone installed Linux on an HP Proliant 365 G1 server?  I can't because it doesn't detect hard drives (Raid5).  Any compatible version?  He read a lot and I think HP Smart Array SCSI driver comes from this but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué versión de Linux deseas instalar?

The driver for this system is the in-kernel CCISS driver/module. If your operating system is too recent, that driver won't be present.

The DL365 G1 is from 2009, so it's a very old server.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I know and I realized very late.  Any other that comes to mind that is functional?

Comment: CentOS6 works for that hardware.